# Azure Python web service fail when open pickle file

Tags: python, azure, iis, deployment

I start web service on azure, deploy the python project(3), it is successfully started, and some routes like:

```
@app.route('/')
   def OK():
   return 'OK!'
```

working ok.

But when requesting this code:

```
@app.route('/predict_states/<userRequests>')
def CreatePrediction(userRequests):
    predict = Predict([userRequests], model)
    return jsonify(predict)
```

the model is:

```
with open("model.pkl", 'rb') as f:
    model = dill.load(f)
```

azure return an error 500:
IIS received the request; however, an internal error occurred during the processing of the request. The root cause of this error depends on which module handles the request and what was happening in the worker process when this error occurred.
IIS was not able to access the web.config file for the Web site or application. This can occur if the NTFS permissions are set incorrectly.
IIS was not able to process configuration for the Web site or application.
The authenticated user does not have permission to use this DLL.
The request is mapped to a managed handler but the .NET Extensibility Feature is not installed.

What could be the problem?

Comment: I am also facing this issue.. did u fix this?

Comment: No. At the moment, i chose standalone Linux server an have no headache